# Element wise comparison between two dataframes (one of them containing lists)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have two two Dataframes and one is made up of list.

```
    in [00]: table01
    out[00]: 
       a  b
    0  1  2
    1  2  3

    in [01]: table02
    out[01]: 
          a     b
    0   [2]   [3]
    1 [1,2] [1,2]
```

And now I want to compare two tables. If the element in table01 also in the same position list of table02, return True otherwise return False. So the table I want to have is:

```
          a     b
    0 False False  
    1  True False
```

I have tried **table01 in table02** but get a error message: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Please share the correct solution of this problem with me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `table01 in table02` is not much of an attempt...

Comment: well, for pure value compare. table01 == table02 works but I can't understand why it doesn't work in my condition. Actually, I find out that if I call cell one by one, use 'in'  and then put the result back  it works. However, my current solution is quit time consuming and that's why I ask this question. Sorry for my unclear statement.

Comment: Because the `==` operator is overloaded to work with dataframes. Element wise comparisons are made, and since int != list, everything is False. `in` doesn't work like this for dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sets` and `df.applymap`:

```
df3 = df1.applymap(lambda x: {x})
df4 = df2.applymap(set)

df3 & df4    
     a   b
0   {}  {}
1  {2}  {}

(df3 & df4).astype(bool)    
       a      b
0  False  False
1   True  False
```

---

[user3847943's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46136371/4909087) is a good alternative, but could be improved using a `set` membership test.

```
def find_in_array(a, b):
    return a in b

for c in df2.columns:
    df2[c] = df2[c].map(set)

vfunc = np.vectorize(find_in_array)

df = pd.DataFrame(vfunc(df1, df2), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
df

       a      b
0  False  False
1   True  False
```

Comment: Hi , if you have time , I got a question ...`df1.apply(lambda x : x.values in df2.loc[x.index,x.name].values)`, why this does not work ...

Comment: @Wen `df2.loc[...]` returns a list item, and a list item doesn't have .values. That's the first problem. The second one is `x.values` is a list, and you can't really do `list1 in list2` in python, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you , seems does not work ..when I do `df1.apply(lambda x :df2.loc[x.index,x.name])` it return df2, which make me think can using this way solve the problem

Comment: @Wen Yeah... `df.apply` behaves weird... I have opened a new question based on it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137355/why-is-pandas-dataframe-apply-printing-out-junk

Comment: Hi, I got it , by using the idea x.index and x.name , and updated ~ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using numpy.vectorize. Sample code as below.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

t1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],[2,3]])
t2 = pd.DataFrame([[[2],[3]],[[1,2],[1,2]]])

def find_in_array(a, b):
    return a in b

vfunc = np.vectorize(find_in_array)

print(vfunc(t1, t2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df=pd.melt(df1.reset_index(),'index')
df['v2']=pd.melt(df2.reset_index(),'index').value
pd.melt(df2.reset_index(),'index')
df['BOOL']=df.apply(lambda x: True if x.value in x.v2 else False, axis = 1)
df.pivot('index','variable','BOOL')

Out[491]: 
variable      a      b
index                 
0         False  False
1          True  False
```

Finally :

```
df1.apply(lambda x: [(x==df2.loc[y,x.name])[y] for y in x.index])
Out[668]: 
       a      b
0  False  False
1   True  False
```