# Why is pandas.DataFrame.apply printing out junk?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Consider this simple dataframe:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
```

I perform a `.apply` as such:

```
In [4]: df.apply(lambda x: [x.values])
Out[4]: 
a    [[140279910807944, 140279910807920]]
b    [[140279910807944, 140279910807920]]
dtype: object

In [5]: df.apply(lambda x: [x.values])
Out[5]: 
a    [[37, 37]]
b    [[37, 37]]
dtype: object

In [6]: df.apply(lambda x: [x.values])
Out[6]: 
a    [[11, 11]]
b    [[11, 11]]
dtype: object
```

Why is pandas printing out junk each time?

I've verified this happens in v0.20.

Edit: Looking for an answer, not a workaround.

Comment: Same with `df.apply(lambda x: [x])`.

Comment: Same with a one-row dataframe: `df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2]})` `df1.apply(lambda x: [x],axis=1)` Output: `0    [[0, 0]]`,

Comment: @DYZ Thanks. So it wasn't just my machine playing the fool.

Comment: Good job breaking `apply`... now you have to fix it!

Comment: @piRSquared it'd be interested to see if this is a bug... :p (it's out of my hands then)

Comment: Can confirm the behavior on `0.21.0.dev+` master branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like bug, so was opened [Issue 17487](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17487).

For me working add `tolist`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: [x.values.tolist()]))
a    [[1, 2]]
b    [[2, 3]]
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: [list(x.values)]))
a    [[1, 2]]
b    [[2, 3]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes... the workaround is alright. My question is why??

Comment: Yes, good question - I have absolutely no idea - but it seems like bug.

Comment: Thank you for opening the issue. If it really is a bug, I think this is the only way we can find out.

Comment: thank you too - I will edit answer if issue is explained.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an answer... just a work around

```
f = lambda x: x.values.reshape(1, -1).tolist()

df.apply(f)

a    [[1, 2]]
b    [[2, 3]]
dtype: object
```

---

I tracked it down to `pd.lib.reduce`

```
pd.lib.reduce(df.values, lambda x: [list(x)])

array([list([[1, 2]]), list([[2, 3]]), list([['a', 'b']])], dtype=object)
```

Versus

```
pd.lib.reduce(df.values, lambda x: [x])

array([list([array([None, None], dtype=object)]),
       list([array([None, None], dtype=object)]),
       list([array([None, None], dtype=object)])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I was checking the same thing in the main [code][1]
  till now from that ` _apply_raw` method. I thought it was the problem with mixed datatype in np.apply_along_axis. But its the `reduce`. Really nice. 
  [1]: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3a7f956c30528736beaae5784f509a76d892e229/pandas/core/frame.py#L4280

Answer (score 3):

Another work around:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [list(x)])
```